# How can create script to get code, publish and run it in some empty machine (NetCore WebApi)

Tags: shell, asp.net-core, clone, publish

I have a doubt.
How can i create scritps to :

- Get my code from repository (GitHub, GitLab...)
- Build
- Publish
- Test
- Run in IIS

This script should run in windows or linux OS, and consider that i have a empty VM.

This application is an .Net Core WebApi.
I searched in web but not found an template geting code from repository.

Comment: "Empty machine" you mean that it's not configured for web? Your request it not just a script, it's a wide system that called CI. TeamCity for exapmle https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity

Comment: This should be doable with scripts, but as @itikhomi says, there are options that are pre-built already. Please provide some code you have tried, rather than just asking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable with scripts like @Scott said and you should consider using solutions for this because there are some great free ones out there like teamcity with octopus integration. Here is what you need to consider if you decide on making scripts for this.

1. The vm you have is empty so the runtimes need to be installed and
   checked are they compatible with code you are trying to deploy to
   them.
2. The scripts for some parts of deployment will need to be run under user with   sufficient privileges
3. You will need to handle the webserver configuration with the scripts as well for all of this

And those only a few things that are on the list for that path. Now having said that there is the path of containers which handle most of this through code and can be deployed to all of environments you mentioned before and you only need to worry that there is a container service on those vm-s you want to deploy to and it will be much easier to handle since like i mentioned it is all in code and is easily changed unlike some scripts.